# Better way to send email to multiple recipients with AdonisJs

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, adonis.js

I want to send newsletters to multiple users, but when I try my code, the emails can be seen by everyone. And if I send it using looping, I'm afraid it will take a long time because there are many users. Is there a good solution to send multiple emails?

This is my code (I use SMTP):

```
await Mail.send('newsletter', data, (message) => {
    message
      .from('newsletter@web.com', 'Admin')
      .subject('New Events Notification')
      .to(emails) // array consist of multiple emails
    })
```

Comment: You can use a proper emailing platform, one I persoanlly use is [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com). They offer a good range of features at reasonable prices, with also a queueing system. It may take a while to setup however once you've set up your account it's pretty striaght forward. However, I'm sure there are many more services like this one out there.

Comment: ohh i see.. so i think it will be hard to find a free one. thank you very much for responding to my first question! @Tyler2P

Comment: Sendgrid offers a [free plan](https://sendgrid.com/free/). You only get half the features what what do you expect, it's free and lasts a lifetime.

Comment: owh.. okay, thank you for the information i will try to read more about sendgrid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sendLater` method to send multiple emails. The Adonis js uses the memory queue inside this method. So it will not block your HTTP request.

**After replacing the method your code will look like this .**

```
await Mail.sendLater('newsletter', data, (message) => {
  message
    .from('newsletter@web.com', 'Admin')
    .subject('New Events Notification')
    .to(emails) // array consist of multiple emails
})
```

Now you can add your loop and Adonis js will send email in background.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just knew about sendLater.. i really appreaciate your help! hope you have a great day